# c# Reading XML with XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

When I run the following code and step through it with a break point and look at temp I see "Empty, Enumeration yielded no results" and the MessageBox.Show never fires. I'm trying to pull everything under Season no="1"

```
XElement sitemap = XElement.Load(@"http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=" + this.showID);
IEnumerable<XElement> temp = from el in sitemap.Elements("Season")
                                         where (string)el.Attribute("no") == "1"
                                         select el;
foreach (XElement el in temp)
{
    MessageBox.Show("found something");
}
```

This is the XML that's being loaded:
http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=6312

Comment: I didn't check thoroughly, but I think `sitemap.Descendants("Season")` would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for elements called `Season` *directly* under the root element... whereas your XML looks like this:

```
<Show>
  <name>The X-Files</name>
  <totalseasons>9</totalseasons>
  <Episodelist>
    <Season no="1">
      <episode>
      ...
```

If you want to look for all descendant elements with a given name, use `Descendants` instead of `Elements`. That certainly finds elements in the example XML you've given.